# What is the Perl equivalent of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in PHP?

Tags: php, perl

How do I get the current domain name in a Perl script, i.e. the equivalent Perl code for the [`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php#HTTP_HOST) PHP variable?

Comment: When asking for equivalents in technologies, please tag it with both names. Provide the documentation or a description so that not only someone who knows both may answer, but also people who only knows one of them. I edited the question to improve this.

Answer (score 8):

The hostname alone is almost never useful, you also want the server port, in combination nicknamed *netloc*. Most likely you need this value to construct a URI to the script. This is already included in the frameworks, no need to do this manually. Code samples for both ways following.

---

In PSGI, read the "variable" `HTTP_HOST` (alternatively, `SERVER_NAME` and `SERVER_PORT`) from the PSGI environment hash, or call the [`uri` method in Plack::Request](http://p3rl.org/Plack::Request#uri).

```
use Plack::Request qw();
my $app = sub {
    my ($env) = @_;
    my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);
    return [200, ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain'], [
        sprintf "Host: %s\nURI: %s", $env->{HTTP_HOST}, $req->uri
    ]];
};
```

---

In CGI, combine the POSIX environment variables [`SERVER_NAME` and `SERVER_PORT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.14), or call the [`url`](http://p3rl.org/CGI#OBTAINING-THE-SCRIPTS-URL) method.

```
use CGI qw();
my $c = CGI->new;
print $c->header('text/plain');
print "Host: $ENV{SERVER_NAME}:$ENV{SERVER_PORT}\n";
print "URI: " . $c->url;
```